# ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't work even storage table is InnoDb

Tags: mysql, database-design

I tear my hair with the ON DELETE CASCADE Clause. In fact I have two tables 
I'm on linux and I have installed lamp with phpmyadmin.

That's the tables :

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    Idatable bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Nameatable varchar(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE anObject(
    IdAnObject bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nameobject varchar(20) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE linkTable(
    Idatable bigint(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES a (Idatable),
    IdAnObject bigint(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES anObject (IdAnObject) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Idatable, IdAnObject),
    CONSTRAINT linkTable_fk1
        FOREIGN KEY (Idatable) 
        REFERENCES a (Idatable),
    CONSTRAINT linkTable_fk2
        FOREIGN KEY (IdAnObject) 
        REFERENCES anObject (IdAnObject) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work because when I delete a row in the table 'linktable' the associated row in anObject isn't delete

Thank you

Comment: It's working perfectly as @ypercube points out. See [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql/74634#74634).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASCADE` clause works in the opposite direction. From the parent to the child table.

When you delete a row in the **parent** table, the related rows in the **child** table are deleted as well.

Comment: Just a thought - not a good idea to permanently delete records. Copy them to a logging table via a trigger or set a Boolean instead.

Comment: @Vérace I don't delete records because my tables have only rows ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ "[Columns are not fields. Rows are not records. Tables are not files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko)" :-)