# Mysql - How to delete a row with foreign key referencing multiple rows

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have a table F:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table_f` (
  `id_f` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `column_F` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_f`),
  INDEX `index2` (`fk_1` ASC, `fk_2` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```
id_f | fk_1  | fk_2  | column_F
-------------------------------
1    | 1     | 1     | AA
2    | 1     | 2     | BB
3    | 1     | 2     | CC  <-- "Duplicate" of row id_f=2 (but valid data)
4    | 2     | 1     | DD
```

And a table A:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table_a` (
  `id_a` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_a`),
  INDEX `a_idx` (`fk_1` ASC, `fk_2` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_1` , `fk_2`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`table_f` (`fk_1` , `fk_2`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```
id_a  | fk_1 | fk_2
---------------------
1     | 1    | 1
2     | 1    | 2
3     | 2    | 1
```

`Table A` has a foreign key as: `[fk_1, fk_2]`, so I ensure that there is, at least, one record in `Table F`.

The problem is, I want to `delete from table_f where id_f=3`. But I cannot, because of the foreign key.

Also, important to notice, the duplicate on `table_f` is on purpose and necessary.

How can I ensure that a table has at least one row on another table, but being able to delete this row later?

Comment: Unclear. Add CREATE TABLE for both tables into the question.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Are you looking for [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74634/34007)`?

Comment: The root of a problem is clear. The index on `F(fk_1, fk_2)` was NOT defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything on `table_a`, just on `table_f`. Even after deleting on `table_f`, `table_a` will continue to have its foreign key

Comment: @Akina it's not supposed to be UNIQUE. I can have more than one row on `table_f`. The data provided in the question is valid. I just cannot delete a row on `table_f` (but I can insert seamlessly)

Comment: If so you will have this problem each time when you need to delete a record.

Comment: From the other side, if `F(fk_1, fk_2)` must NOT to be unique then your data is not normalized.

Comment: No, it's not. But I really don't know how to do that with my data, which involves arrays of specific types (saved on other 2 tables). And it's supper complex and big that I can't make it small enough to ask on StackExchange. I'd really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem to me. You seem to misunderstand how referential integrity constraints work.

Comment: *No, it's not.* Normalized reference must be deterministic. Non-unique index can NOT provide deterministic reference.

Comment: @Akina I created the question about my real problem. Probably it'll be flagged to be deleted, but if you have a spare time and could help me, [this is the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256809/how-to-normalize-a-database-which-uses-tables-as-references-to-other-tables)

Comment: The way to normalizing is in moving `(fk_1, fk_2)` pair into separate table, where this pair is defined as UNIQUE. And both `A` and `F` references to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may disable FKs (`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`), delete record, then enable FKs back. But it is too unsafe - this setting affects to all. Less (slightly) unsafe is `SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`.

You may remove FK, delete record, then restore FK. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5881b1bf4a4125764e635530ea8bfbe8). Pay attention - `CONSTRAINT symbol` is used. It is less unsafe.

Or you may edit the record(s) which references to duplicated records. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad1f5249a73fb3e6e07b88f56daf0d6f). Pay attention - only one record must be deleted. It is minimal unsafe.

In both variants - deleting wrong (unique) record will forbid re-create FK or re-assign referential fields.

**UPDATE:**

The most safe method (it seems) is to use `EVENT` which sets `SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` and deletes the record. This guarantees that no interference occured (because it is executed in separate session), except some DELETE trigger on table `F` exists.

Nevertheless if you delete wrong (unique) record you'll have a problem...