# How to normalize a database which uses tables as references to other tables?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I'm trying to create the database for my application, but I cannot manage to normalize my data on a MySQL database.

- I have a `Types` of map entity
- The `Types` must have one or more Models associated to it, in a particular `order`
- The `Models` have a `Grid`, `is_prediction` flag and an `Origin` associated to it
- There can be more than one `Model` using the same `Grid`, `Origin` and `is_prediction` condition, differing only on the `name` of the model
- Not all `Origins` provide all the `Models`
- The `Types` can only have `Models` associated to it that have the same condition of `[Grid, Origin, is_prediction]`

I tried to create a table `types_hierarchy`, using `grid_id, origin_id and is_prediction` as foreign key, but it seems wrong, according to the answer on my other question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256805/mysql-how-to-delete-a-row-with-foreign-key-referencing-multiple-rows).

How can I create a normalized database for my needs?

This is what I tried to do:

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

As per your other post, if you require such delete requirements, it is surely a poor design.

Secondly, there is **no** "so called" The Best Design.

Third, do not get struck with heavy normalization though essential. Design in such a way that you arrive at a maximum normalization and put it to use. While Beta testing...you shall refine to an extent.

And finally, even if we review / amend your design details, that might not be a best match for your exact requirement. instead, with your given details, if you would have added any particular issue which you foresee, we shall advise on the same.