# Modify parent's and child's foreign key value of a record

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Consider following relationship on MySQL database.

```
+--------------+                   +---------------+
|     Child    |                   |    Parent     |
+--------------+                 1 +---------------+
| child_id (PK)| 1           |-----| parent_id (PK)|
| parent_id(FK)|-------------|     | name          |
| name         |                   | address       |
| age          |                   +---------------+
| gender       |                  
| grade        |
+--------------+
```

I want to update a record `where parent_id = 100`. My requirement is to modify to `parent_id=101`. Assume there is no records as 101. This operation need to update `child.parent_id = 101` as well so the original relation remains.

My current approach is, roughly

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
UPDATE Child SET parent_id=101 WHERE parent_id=100;
UPDATE Parent SET parent_id=101 WHERE parent_id=100;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

COMMIT;
```

- Can this be problematic in production environment where thousands of writes per second done?
- Is there a proper way I can achieve this without disabling foreign key checks?

Comment: The proper way is to create the foreing key constraint with the ON UPDATE CASCADE option: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: `modify to parent_id=101` -- Are you running an adoption agency?  Seriously, there is virtually no database need to modify a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Does your code fail without the `SETs`?  (And didn't you mean `1` for the final `SET`?)

Comment: @RickJames yes, I meant `1`, sorry for typo. Yah, I want to run adoption agency in a legal way. Jokes aside, this is just an abstraction of a scenario happened to me few days ago. I was trying to perform a soft delete then add another record (child and parent) with same primary keys. I wondered if I ever happened to perform such thing on a production environment (hypothetically) what are my options to do it safely. This is the explanation, but this question is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: (I'm not a fan of FKs; there are so many situations where users stumble over the limitations and tricky things.  As for `CASCADE`, I prefer to write code to do such instead of it silently happening.)